# Select polars columns by index

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe of species, 89 date columns and 23 unique species. The goal is aggregation by a groupby as well as a range of columns. iloc would be the way to do this in pandas, but the select option doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

In pandas:

```
gb = df.groupby(["Common_name"]).agg(dict(zip(df.iloc[:, 32:103].columns, ["mean"] * len(df.iloc[:, 32:103]))))
```

is there a way to select column indices in polars?

Comment: Is that not the same as `df.columns[32:103]`?

Comment: ah. yes. forgot it's much simpler than that.